# Rewrite URL to different directory and change extension

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a problem with some rewrites that I have checked extensively in:
https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

But on the web server don't work as expected.

My rules are:

```
ReWriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$                  /content/index.php          [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$    /content/$1/$2.php          [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$             /content/$1/index.php       [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$              /content/$1/index.php       [L]
```

Example URLs are:

```
https://domain.tld -> /content/index.php
https://domain.tld/ -> /content/index.php

https://domain.tld/path -> /content/path/index.php
https://domain.tld/path/ -> /content/path/index.php
https://domain.tld/path/page.html -> /content/path/page.php

https://domain.tld/path/more -> /content/path/more/index.php
https://domain.tld/path/more/ -> /content/path/more/index.php
https://domain.tld/path/more/page.html -> /content/path/more/page.php
```

I'm getting an internal server error, even though the pages don't have anything on them. If I remove the routing I get the 404 fine.

Any help appreciated. If you need more info just ask.

Comment: So what does your http server's error log file say what the actual issue is?

Comment: Ah, you obviously get a redirection loop using above setup. Any rewritten request will get rewritten again and again, since you rewrite _everything_ unconditionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this rules on the top of your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /content/

# path/more/page.html -> /content/path/more/page.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/(.*)\.html$    /$1/$2/$3.php  [L]

# path/more/ -> /content/path/more/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\/$    /$1/$2/index.php  [L]

# path/page.html -> /content/path/page.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)\.html$    /$1/$2.php  [L]

# path/more -> /content/path/more/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(.*)$    /$1/$2/index.php  [L]

# path/ -> /content/path/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$    /$1/index.php  [L]

# path -> /content/path/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    /$1/index.php  [L]

# / -> /content/index.php
RewriteRule ^\/$    /index.php  [L]

# https://domain.tld -> /content/index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L]
```